# Set height of background image in uc browser

Tags: css, uc-browser

I have problem with `css` on `uc browser`.

```css
.note-sec
    {
        padding-bottom:50px;
        background:url(../img/4.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
        width:auto;
        display:block;
        height:100%!important;
        min-height:300px;
        color:#fff
    }
```

in many browser like chrome, its working well.but in uc browser, the image width 100%, not height 100%. any ideas ?thanks

Comment: providing screenshot of your issue make some sense

Comment: please look [screenshot on uc browser android](http://prnt.sc/eebph1) . the background image not height 100%. thanks

Answer (score 0):

UC Browser treats `height: 100%` differently and won't inherit from grandparent nodes.

What you need to do here is provide a fixed height to the parent of `.note-sec` and make the `display` property of the same as `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: please see screenshot above

Comment: nope still doesn't work. It only occurs on UC Browser. Here my fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/g67j4smL/  It works on **ALL** browsers except UC Browser.